# SHA256 password hash generation and verification

Tags: php, authentication, codeigniter

I would like to optimise this code. It seems a bit verbose, particularly with the 'elseif' that doesn't do anything.

This code either:

- takes a plain text password, generates a salt, and returns them both OR
- takes a plain text password and a salt with which to encrypt the password, and returns them both (even though the salt has already been supplied).

```
class Member extends ActiveRecord\Model {

private function process_password($password, $salt = '') {
    /**
     * Process a password to encrypt it for storage or verification.
     * @param string - plain text password for processing.
     * @access private
     * @return array Containing the encrypted password and the salt.
     */

    //Check if the salt has been supplied. If not, generate one.
    if (!$salt) {
        $salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    } elseif ($salt && strlen($salt) == 64)  {
        //Do nothing, the salt has already been supplied here.
    } else {
        log_message('info', 'Supplied password to process_password() was not the correct 64-byte length.');
        return false;
    }

    $hashed_password = hash('sha256', $password.$salt);

    return array('password' => $hashed_password, 'salt' => $salt);

}
}
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of that empty `elseif`, just change it to `strlen($salt) != 64` and put the `else` code in the `elseif` block.

Comment: Your code looks like already optimized! Is it working? If so why change?

Comment: @B4NZ41 I've tried my best to optimise it, but I'm trying to learn to code a bit more 'profesionally'. Particularly by getting rid of the extra elseif! :)

Comment: I'm a big fan of removing nesting whenever possible. See [this](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses) for more information. Bad formatting since I can't post an answer on closed questions, so here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eDr5qH2Q).

Comment: Please disregard the pastebin as it has an error. I am still a fan of reducing nesting, but I no longer think it makes a difference here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following:

```
if (!$salt) {
    $salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
} elseif (strlen($salt) !== 64)  {
    log_message('info', 'Supplied password to process_password() was not the correct 64-byte length.');
    return false;
}
// if we're here, we have a valid salt
```

Improvements

- Removed `$salt` from second condition (already known to be TRUE)
- Flipped length logic, moved else code into second block
- Removed empty condition block

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce your if/elseif/else to:

```
if (!$salt) {
    $salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
} elseif (strlen($salt) !== 64)  {
    log_message('info', 'Supplied password to process_password() was not the correct 64-byte length.');
    return false;
}
```

You already know that `$salt` is truthy since you check in the `if` part, so all you care about is that it's valid (length 64).

A way to further improve this would be to [use a standard password hashing library instead of using PHP's built in hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581919/212555). For example, yours has a major potential problem: It's way too fast. With enough hardware, an attacker could just brute force any short passwords.